# List view within View Pager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, scroll, android-viewpager

I have a view pager with about 8 pages, each containing a list view. I'm using a `fragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public NewsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Category selectedCategory = fragmentCategories.get(position);
        HeadlinesFragment fragment = HeadlinesFragment.create(
                selectedCategory.getCategoryID(),
                selectedCategory.getLastEventID());

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentCategories.size();
    }
}

ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The offscreen page limit for the view pager is defaulted to 1.The list view for each page is being populated with data from SQLite. The view pager works fine when you swipe through the pages to the right.

But when I swipe left to the immediate previous page (let's call it page X), the list view for that previous page blocks/ lags - It stops scrolling. However when I swipe a number of pages to the left, and then swipe right till I reach page X, since the list view is reloaded, it scrolls fin.